# GTK# Textview for line-numbering

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

Trying to develop a text editor using gtk#. Is there a easy way for text editor to represent the line number at the left side of the text. I require guidance of which widget I should use and how to use it.

Comment: I don't think so, you'll probably have to code it yourself. You could encapsulate it inside your own widget that uses the textview within, or if you want to get really fancy you could write your own text editor widget from the ground up using Pango for text layouts. Neither of those options are 'easy' though, sorry.

Comment: @muszeo I tried packing two textview with a Hbox, but line height really bothers me. I tried getting line height with textView.GetLineYrange and setting the height offset to line numbering view with texttag (pixelAboveLines), but it is still abit off....